# synchronous calls (await ad.authenticate)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, node-modules

How can I make an asynchronous call? i tried with this code:

```
abc = await ad.authenticate(username, password, function(err, auth) {
          if(err){
            console.log('ERROR: '+JSON.stringify(err));
            fail_found = err.name;
            return;
          }

          if(auth){
            console.log('Authenticated!');
          }else{
            console.log('Authenticated Faliled');
            fail_found = 'No Authenticated ';
          }          
        });
      }
      console.log("Fails?: ",fail_found);
```

NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory2
Github:  https://github.com/jsumners/node-activedirectory/

Thx !

Comment: first link you posted, `A Promise wrapper is available for all methods by an alternate require statement`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try With a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise):

```
let myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     ad.authenticate(username, password, function(err, auth) {
      if(err){
        console.log('ERROR: '+JSON.stringify(err));
        fail_found = err.name;
        reject(fail_found)
        return;
      }

      if(auth){
        console.log('Authenticated!');
        resolve('Authenticated!');
      }else{
        console.log('Authenticated Faliled');
        fail_found = 'No Authenticated ';
        reject(fail_found)
      }          
    });
  }
  console.log("Fails?: ",fail_found);
  reject(fail_found)
});

myPromise.then((successMessage) => {
 console.log(successMessage);
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Or in the first part of documentation show a **promiseWrapper**:

```
const AD = require('activedirectory2').promiseWrapper;
const config = { url: 'ldap://dc.domain.com',
           baseDN: 'dc=domain,dc=com',
           username: 'username@domain.com',
           password: 'password' }
const ad = new AD(config);
```

Comment: But ist not Synchronous ..
```
console.log(' ----- start');
    myPromise.then((successMessage) => {
      console.log(successMessage);
   }).catch(err => {
     console.log(err)
   });
console.log(' ----- end');
```

Comment: i will for example first check if user exist, them check if can authenticate , but wenn user not exist i dont need check the authentication .

Wenn ist async this check both at same time.

Comment: Now is OK, i forget the async function asd (){ await .... , await ...}   . Thanks, Gracias :)